# ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `titleweb_poster` is not valid for model `ContestDetail`

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have wriiten some code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1UHf8Zv_). Please check out the file. When I filled all the fields from django admin then it's working but when I redirect it with http://127.0.0.1:8000/contest/ then I am getting below error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `titleweb_poster` is not valid for model `ContestDetail`.
```

Where I did wrong? How can I solve it?

Comment: You are missing a comma between fields here `'title' 'web_poster'` (serializers.py). This is a very basic error.

Comment: @Borut uff it was a very basic mistake. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In serializers.py you're missing a comma `,` between `title` and `web_poster` in `ContestDetailSerial.Meta.fields`.